# Using Rust actix_cors and cannot get the server to wrap my cors settings

Tags: rust, cors, actix-web

I have tried this many ways without success. I can get to the backend api and get json as a result with a browser straight to url http://127.0.0.1/data, but when trying to access it with my front end (coming from http://127.0.0.1:8080) I get the following error:

Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8082/data' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is my backend's HttpServer with CORS:

```
// Create CORS middleware with your desired configuration
let cors = Cors::default()
    .allowed_origin("http://localhost:8080")
    .allow_any_header()
    .allow_any_method()
    .expose_any_header();

// Start HTTP server with `db_pool` passed as state and CORS middleware...
HttpServer::new(move || {
    App::new()
        .wrap(cors)
        .app_data(web::Data::new(db_pool.clone()))
        // Pass the database pool
        .service(web::resource("/data").route(web::get().to(get_data))) // Set up your routes
})
```

I get the following error and my project doesn't compile:

```
error\[E0277\]: the trait bound `Cors: Transform<actix_web::app_service::AppRouting, ServiceRequest>` is not satisfied
\--\> src\\main.rs:46:15
|
46  |         .wrap(cors)
|          ---- ^^^^ the trait `Transform<actix_web::app_service::AppRouting, ServiceRequest>` is not implemented for `Cors`
|          |
|          required by a bound introduced by this call
|
= help: the following other types implement trait `Transform<S, Req>`:
    \<actix_service::transform_err::TransformMapInitErr\<T, S, Req, F, E\> as Transform\<S, Req\>\>
    \<Compat\<T\> as Transform\<S, Req\>\>
    \<Condition\<T\> as Transform\<S, Req\>\>
    \<ErrorHandlers\<B\> as Transform\<S, ServiceRequest\>\>
    \<Rc\<T\> as Transform\<S, Req\>\>
    \<Arc\<T\> as Transform\<S, Req\>\>
    \<DefaultHeaders as Transform\<S, ServiceRequest\>\>
    \<Logger as Transform\<S, ServiceRequest\>\>
    and 2 others
    note: required by a bound in `App::<T>::wrap`
    \--\> C:\\Users\\user.cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\actix-web-      4.4.0\\src\\app.rs:351:12
|
338 |       pub fn wrap\<M, B\>(
|              ---- required by a bound in this associated function
...
351 |           M: Transform\<
|  __^
352 | |                 T::Service,
353 | |                 ServiceRequest,
354 | |                 Response = ServiceResponse\<B\>,
355 | |                 Error = Error,
356 | |                 InitError = (),
357 | |             \> + 'static,
| |__\_^ required by this bound in `App::<T>::wrap`
\`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I tried the above and it doesn't compile and my front end cant access the data due to the CORS issue. If I remove the .wrap(cors) it does compile but I can't access it from my front end. I can however get to it from a browser url going straight to http://127.0.0.1:8082/data

I am still learning so I am unable to make sense of my error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What dependency and version does `Cors` come from and what version of Actix Web are you using? You may be using incompatible versions.

Comment: This is my cargo.toml:

`[dependencies]  
actix-web = "4.0"  
sqlx = { version = "0.5", features = ["postgres", "runtime-actix-native-tls", "macros",  
 "chrono"] }  
dotenv = "0.15"  
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }  
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }  
actix-cors = "0.5.4"  `

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

move cors declaration and initialization into the HttpServer::

```
HttpServer::new(move || {
    let cors = Cors::default()
    .allowed_origin("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
    .allow_any_header()
    .allow_any_method()
    .expose_any_header();

    App::new()
        .wrap(cors)
        .app_data(web::Data::new(db_pool.clone()))
        // Pass the database pool
        .service(web::resource("/data").route(web::get().to(get_data))) // Set up your routes
    // ... other configuration ...
})
.bind("127.0.0.1:8082")? // Specify the address to bind
.run()                  // Run the server
.await
}
```

And update to latest crate versions:

```
actix-web = "4.4.0"
actix-cors = "0.6.5"
```

Comment: Please remove the solution from your question and put it here instead. Glad you were able to figure it out.